# moving ResultSet cursor forward and backward in a JDBC application

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working on a Stock Inventory System software which connects to a Ms Sql server using a JDBC ODBC connection. I want to move the Result Set cursor to the next row and backwards. The connection works and the program can retrieve the fields from the database, so there's no issue with that.

The code that I have here is a on a button labeled "Next". *When you click this button it should move to the next row in the database and retrieve the data from that row. The data retrieved should be displayed in the "textfields".* The problem is when I click next nothing happens?

```
    private void NextBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc");
        Connection con;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:StockInventory","sa","123");           

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String query = "select * from Stocktbl";

        ResultSet rs; 
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query); 


        if(!rs.isLast()) {
            rs.next();

            TxtStockid.setText(rs.getString("StockId"));
            TxtItem.setText(rs.getString("ItemName"));
            TxtQuantity.setText(rs.getString("Quantity"));
            TxtUnitprice.setText(rs.getString("UnitPrice"));
            TxtNetprice.setText(rs.getString("NetPrice"));
            TxtUnitweight.setText(rs.getString("UnitWeight"));
            TxtNetweight.setText(rs.getString("Netweight"));
            TxtDescription.setText(rs.getString("Description"));
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();




    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(StockScr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(StockScr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }       
}
```

Here is the rest of the coding for the program, The "Next" button is added to this Panel.

```
public class StockScr extends javax.swing.JPanel {
ResultSet rs;
Connection con = null;

public StockScr() {
    initComponents();
    ShowTable();

}

void ShowTable(){
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc");
        Connection con;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:StockInventory","sa","123");           

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        String query = "select * from Stocktbl";           
        ResultSet rs; 
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        rs.first();
            TxtStockid.setText(rs.getString("StockId"));
            TxtItem.setText(rs.getString("ItemName"));
            TxtQuantity.setText(rs.getString("Quantity"));
            TxtUnitprice.setText(rs.getString("UnitPrice"));
            TxtNetprice.setText(rs.getString("NetPrice"));
            TxtUnitweight.setText(rs.getString("UnitWeight"));
            TxtNetweight.setText(rs.getString("Netweight"));
            TxtDescription.setText(rs.getString("Description"));

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();

    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(StockScr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(StockScr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
}


public void fetchResultSet()
{

try {
    if(con==null || con.isClosed())
    {
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:StockInventory","sa","123");           
    }
    Statement stmt =     con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    String query = "select * from Stocktbl";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query); 
  }catch(Exception ex){
     System.out.println(ex);
     Logger.getLogger(StockScr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
  }

     try
     {
        if(con != null)
        {
          con.close();
        }
     }catch(Exception ex){

     }

}


private void NextBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

try
{

 if (rs == null)
 {
    fetchResultSet();
 }

 if (rs!=null)
 {
    if (rs.next())
    {
        TxtStockid.setText(rs.getString("StockId"));
        TxtItem.setText(rs.getString("ItemName"));
        TxtQuantity.setText(rs.getString("Quantity"));
        TxtUnitprice.setText(rs.getString("UnitPrice"));
        TxtNetprice.setText(rs.getString("NetPrice"));
        TxtUnitweight.setText(rs.getString("UnitWeight"));
        TxtNetweight.setText(rs.getString("Netweight"));
        TxtDescription.setText(rs.getString("Description"));         
    }
   else
   {
      rs = null;
   }
 }
}catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.println(ex); 
  }        
}
```

Comment: Why are you establishing connection and retrieving data each time your `Next` button is clicked?

Comment: Actually I want to be able to click the next button and it should retrieve the data from the next row in the databae and display that in a textfield. I'm not sure if i need to establish the connection again for that or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should creat Connection to database and fetch fresh record only once before you are clicking `next` button. And then keep moving forward using `rs.next` in `NextBtnActionPerformed` method.

For example you should have a method call fetchResultSet as follows and that should be called before`next` button is clicked.

```
ResultSet rs;
Connection con = null;
public void fetchResultSet()
{

   try {
        if(con==null || con.isClosed())
        {
          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:StockInventory","sa","123");           
        }
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        String query = "select * from Stocktbl";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query); 
      }catch(Exception ex)
      {
         System.out.println(ex);
         Logger.getLogger(StockScr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

         try
         {
            if(con != null)
            {
              con.close();
            }
         }catch(Exception x){}
      }
}
```

And then your `NextBtnActionPerformed` should be like this:

```
private void NextBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
  try
  {
     if (rs == null)
     {
        fetchResultSet();
     }
     if (rs!=null)
     {
        if (rs.next())
        {
            TxtStockid.setText(rs.getString("StockId"));
            TxtItem.setText(rs.getString("ItemName"));
            TxtQuantity.setText(rs.getString("Quantity"));
            TxtUnitprice.setText(rs.getString("UnitPrice"));
            TxtNetprice.setText(rs.getString("NetPrice"));
            TxtUnitweight.setText(rs.getString("UnitWeight"));
            TxtNetweight.setText(rs.getString("Netweight"));
            TxtDescription.setText(rs.getString("Description"));         
        }
       else
       {
          rs = null;
       }
     }
  }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}
}
```

Comment: my Netbeans ide is giving me an error on this line `if(con != null)` "variable con might not have been initialized"

Comment: @Anafam: yes it should have initialized with null..See my update. I have made one more change ..`Connection con` is declared as member variable..so that it is not created each time `fetchResultSet` is called..

Comment: I clicked next but it did "not" move to the next record and my console outputs: `java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed`

Comment: Is some error printing within your `Logger` file? make the `Exception ex` to be printed in `fetchResultSet` method also..

Comment: yes the logger file is printing some errors, should i post them?

Comment: LOL, the logger files is really big...                              `Bad Checksum - idPage: 458754, tyPage: 0, iPage: 18`
`Bad Checksum - idPage: 458757, tyPage: 0, iPage: 19`
`Bad Checksum - idPage: 786433, tyPage: 5, iPage: 24`
`Bad Checksum - idPage: 851990, tyPage: 1, iPage: 22`                but here is the last 4 lines of codes

Comment: @Anafam: It hardly give any clue..lol..You better tell me the exception printed out in your console for `fetchResultSet` method. See my updated code..I have made the `Exception` to print on console within `fetchResultSet` method.

Comment: the line `Logger.getLogger(StockScr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);` needs a `}` closing brace and I ran the program but it's still not moving to the next record. The console outputs again: `java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed`

Comment: do check out my updated post above for additional information.

Comment: Are you were using the method that I posted in my answer.. ??

Comment: yes of course, this is just the original coding that i had before. I have already added the fetchResultSet() method to this program.

Comment: alright, I just updated what the program seems to look like now...BTW there are other methods in this class which i haven't included for the sake of simplicity but those methods works flawlessly and have very little impact on the rest of the coding.

Comment: @Anafam: I am not seeing any change...The post is same as it was..I asked for the new code that you wrote using my code..so that i could see the syntactical issue if any in your new code..

Comment: I did update it using your code, plz refresh your browser. Its the second code field in the post. You just have to scroll down a little to see it :)

Comment: @Anafam `Logger.getLogger(StockScr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
  }` remove `}` from this line.. and add an extra `}` in the last of this method.

Comment: I removed the `}` and added it to the end of the fetchResultSet() method but now i get an error on the line `}catch(Exception ex){` it says "variable ex is already defined in the method fetchResultSet()"

Comment: @Anafam: my mistake.. change the `catch(Exception ex)` to `catch(Exception e)` after `con.close()` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `rs.next()` *before* you can call `rs.isLast()`. The call to `rs.isLast()` does not offer much in terms of functionality:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    TxtStockid.setText(rs.getString("StockId"));
    ...
```

With this approach, you're not advancing the `ResultSet` cursor so get the same data each time a button is clicked. A `WHERE` clause would be required to return a *different* row.  If the total amount of records is not large, caching the data would be the preferred approach.

Caching is suitable where the amount of items is relatively small and large scale scaling up is not required. In this case, you could load all data into an `ArrayList<MyStockItem>` at startup and navigate though the `List` rather than making database connections. Products such as [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) are useful for this purpose.

Comment: i tried doing it this way like you said many times over but it doesn't work

Comment: Does it 1) Retrieve any data? 2) If you going with this approach you will need to use a WHERE clause to get the next available record. If the total amount of records is not large, caching the data would seem like a good solution.

Comment: It does not retrieve any data at all rather it stays on the same record(the 1st record) which was previously set in the textfields using a working code in the program. I'm not to sure how I would implement a WHERE clause. There's only 5 records added till now

Comment: I'd say cache all data into an `ArrayList<MyStockItem>` at startup then navigate through on button click. This is less costly then querying the DB every time.

Comment: that's Cool stuff but I'm afraid I have to make this application using a JDBC connection. "It's a requirement" :)

Answer (score 1):

**You create new result set on every button click**. So new result set has it's cursor on first position and that's why you always get the same record while clicking it. To solve it you need to create result set field, then fill it with records in your main class' constrcutor and then operate on this result set.

Comment: There is no Main class constructor its just a simple class called "StockScr" which extends JPanel. ex: public class StockScr extends JPanel The Next Button is added to this Panel using Netbeans design view.

Comment: So create it in StockScr's constructor, that's what I thought saying main class. Anyway, the problem is as I described - creating new result set on every action performed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
while(rs.next())  instead of if(!rs.isLast())  and then rs.next()
```

I dont think resultset provide the api to move backward. Question is why do you need it.

Comment: LOL, If I can make it move forward to the next record in the database then i'm pretty sure i can do the same for the backward coding on the "Previous" button.

Comment: btw I already tried `while(rs.next())` and all it does is move it to the last record.